# [Python]When should we capitalize all the letters in variables?

Tags: variables, naming-conventions

I am reading a script, which is about game design.

At the very beginning, it gives

```
SCREEN_X = 600
SCREEN_Y = 600
```

I don't know why the author writes it in this way. Is it a personal habit or convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per python.org:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants

Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include MAX_OVERFLOW and TOTAL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to search 'constants' in python.org, but can't find anything about it. Could you show me where can I find it, please?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants